# How to query data by search key in get endpoint

Tags: java, spring, api, swagger

I want to get some filtered entities by GET endpoint. This should be done by one not hardcoded parameter (e.g id, name, description, ...). I thought about smoething like that I have two params: searchKey and searchValue.

```
http://localhost:8080/api/cars?searchKey=name&searchValue=peugeot
```

But it doesn't look good. What are better scenarios for this problem?

Comment: What is wrong with searchKey and searchValue?

Comment: I thought there are better ways to achieve this goal than that. It looks like easiest solution but not best one .

Comment: Since you mention Spring I assume you use Springfox. OpenAPI 3.0 Specification actually supports [free-form query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49582559/113116), but Springfox [does not support OpenAPI 3.0](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2022) yet.

Comment: Related: [RESTful URL design for search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/207477/113116) and [How to design RESTful search/filtering?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5020704/113116)

Answer (score 0):

I would personally like to create a new route *http://localhost:8080/api/cars/search* and provide the POST-verb to this route. This is kind of a resource creation... a new search-resource. So all in all the URL is readable and understandable + the search params are in the POST-body.

You can create a great discussion about RESTful or not... but I think it is important what you and especially your API consumers like to use!