# How to show dynamic fields on swagger ui using springfox

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I have an api that accepts any param by query string.
I want to use springfox to document it but the ui does not allow me to show a field to send.

When I set the controller to accept a `Map<String, String>`, I can deal with params under controller, but the ui does not show as expected.

```java
@RequestParam Map<String, String> allParams
```

[image]

When I set send value, the interface send the field `allParams` with value that I sent. Like:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost/articles/term?allParams=term%3Dvalue"
```

[image]

I want set multiple values or send the full query string. Is it possible to show a field to send all query string like `term=value` or some like this?

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost/articles/term?term=value&otherterm=othervalue"
```

I am using spring 2.3.1 and springfox 2.9.2

Comment: To specify the parameter values, you'll need to click "try it out" first. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49587746/113116

Comment: Hi @Helen when i click on "try it out" it send the value inside allParams field, I want to send each value on each field.

Comment: Just to clarify - even though you enter all parameters in the same field, they will actually be sent as separate `key=value` pairs in the query string. There's also an existing feature request to add a form-like editor for object/map parameters - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2771

Comment: As I explained before, when I send values on the field, the reques resulted is `/term?allParams=term%3Dvalue`, what I want is `/term?term=value`

Comment: Can you please post your OpenAPI YAML/JSON file? Here's how to export it from Swagger UI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48525934. Can you also post the full declaration with annotations of the controller method?

Comment: I am using `swagger: "2.0"`

Comment: OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: '2.0'`) doesn't support objects and maps in the query string - that's probably why it doesn't work. The API definition needs to be in the OpenAPI 3.0 format (`openapi: 3.0.0`). You'll need to upgrade Springfox to v. 3.0.0 to generate an OpenAPI 3.0 API definition.

Comment: I have updated to Springfox to v. 3.0.0 and the data was sent correctly, but now interface do not show example values, neither than json docs