# Cannot pass dynamic query parameters when using `express-openapi-validator`

Tags: openapi, express-openapi-validator

The idea is taken from [here stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49587746/6892277)

After adding a parameter that is supposed do allow dynamic query parameters, it gives error.

Query Example:

```yaml
/pets:
    get:
      description: |
        Returns all pets
      operationId: findPets
      parameters:
        - name: params
          in: query
          required: false
          schema:
            type: object
            # If the parameter values are of specific type, e.g. string:
            # additionalProperties:
            #   type: string
            # If the parameter values can be of different types
            # (e.g. string, number, boolean, ...)
            additionalProperties: true

          # `style: form` and `explode: true` is the default serialization method
          # for query parameters, so these keywords can be omitted
          style: form
          explode: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: pet response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
        default:
          description: unexpected error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
```

Executing a query, returns

```json
{"message":"Cannot convert undefined or null to object"}
```

**To Reproduce**

- Clone [this repository](https://github.com/sabbiu/openapi-demo-project)
- run `npm install`
- run `npm start`
- run `curl http://localhost:3000/v1/pets\?type\=dog\&limit\=10\&test\=query`

**Expected behavior**
It must allow all the query strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the bug in the `express-openapi-validator` package.

> It is now fixed in `v4.4.2`

To test out the functionality, see [this example project](https://github.com/sabbiu/openapi-demo-project)