# Swagger dynamic parameter name and value

Tags: java, rest, swagger, swagger-ui, dropwizard

How to make a request on swagger UI in which i can add N amount of query parameters (both name and value of the parameters have to accept any input) using solely swagger annotations (no openApi yaml/json)?

The request should look something like this:

`GET swagger/users?name1=value1&name2=value`

Swagger UI version is 3.23.0

Comment: See if this helps: [How to document dynamic query parameter names in OpenAPI (Swagger)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49582559/113116)

Comment: @Helen
I have already tried this. It works perfectly in swagger editor using the yaml file, but i need to achieve this using only swagger annotations. I tried writing the code using annotations which seems to be equivalent to the yaml like this: 

`@Parameter(in=ParameterIn.QUERY,    name="params", style=ParameterStyle.FORM,    schema=@Schema(type="object", additionalProperties = Schema.AdditionalPropertiesValue.TRUE), explode=Explode.TRUE)`

 , but it doesn't work, swagger interprets this as a body somehow and shows an error that a GET request can't have a body.

Comment: Can you post the complete method declaration with all annotations?

Comment: @Helen 
It looks like this:

`public String myMethod(@Context Request request,@Context UriInfo uriInfo, @QueryParam("a") Optional<String> a, @QueryParam("b") Optional<String> b, @QueryParam("c") Optional<String> c,  @QueryParam("d") Optional<String> d, @QueryParam("e") Optional<String> e,
@QueryParam("f") Optional<String> f,  @Parameter(in=ParameterIn.QUERY,
name="params", style=ParameterStyle.FORM,
schema=@Schema(type="object", additionalProperties = Schema.AdditionalPropertiesValue.TRUE), explode=Explode.TRUE) String additionParams ){

 //code
}`

Comment: I have also tried removing the `additionalProperties = Schema.AdditionalPropertiesValue.TRUE`  but the result is the same